# Warning message: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge

Tags: generalized-linear-model, predictive-models

GLM model raises a warning regarding glm.fit: algorithm did not converge. I have two ideas to solve the problem.

1. Force the initial model with a warning with stepAIC, then use the final model produced with the stepAIC method, which does not produce a warning, and then make predictions. The initial model and the final model are two different model
2. Delete variables in the initial model until no warnings appear in the GLM model, then do stepAIC and model predictions.

Which way is better, or are there other ideas for this problem? Thank You

[image]

Comment: This warning usually means your data exhibits [perfect separation](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logistic-regression-and-what-are-some-strategies-to-deal-with-the-issue/) and I think stepAIC may not be the best solution, some type of penalized regression may be better.

Comment: So, a better way is to use method number 2 and panelized regression? I also want to ask if the model in StepAIC displays warnings regarding glm.fit: The algorithm did not converge even though the initial model did not display these warnings. Does this indicate that the initial model is not good, or can I ignore these warnings and use the final model? For example, only using the model in the red box below

Comment: regarding the screenshot of the model u can check it above. Thank you

Comment: Sorry Angelina, I don't understand why your smaller model produces the warning but your larger model doesn't. This seems highly unusual to me as the warning is usually due to a particular predictor. In any case, I'd first try the diagnostic procedures suggested [here](https://www.bookdown.org/rwnahhas/RMPH/blr-separation.html) and generally go through the data to try to understand what's "weird". If the problem is perfect or quasi-complete separation, I believe elastic net or ridge regression are often recommended as remedies.